# Custom Adapters for GridView in Android

Tags: android

I have experience getting ListAdapters working, and have looked online for tutorials on custom adapters to interface with a GridView, but I can't seem to get mine working. I'm receiving a NullPointerException on my line:

```
image.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

My Activity and Adapter are as follows:
FixtureActivity:

```
package net.blakely.paul.Hyperion;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class FixtureActivity extends SherlockActivity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fixtures);
        FixtureItemAdapter fia = new FixtureItemAdapter(this, 6);
        GridView grids = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grids);
        grids.setAdapter(fia);

        }

}
```

FixtureItemAdapter:

```
package net.blakely.paul.Hyperion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FixtureItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    public int size;
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView label;

    public FixtureItemAdapter(Activity context, int size) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.v("Hyperion","convertView is Null?="+Boolean.toString(convertView==null));
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(net.blakely.paul.Hyperion.R.layout.outputitem, null, true);

            image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(net.blakely.paul.Hyperion.R.id.imageView1);
            Log.v("Hyperion","image is Null?="+Boolean.toString(image==null));
            label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(net.blakely.paul.Hyperion.R.id.textView2);


        } 

        // Decide which channel this is and set information accordingly

        image.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        label.setText("LABEL");

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. For what it's worth. I've found that I get the NPE on the first run through the adapter, when convertView is null, and image winds up being null as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I found out my problem. It turned out that I was calling the wrong xml file, outputitem instead of fixtureitem, since I had copied that line from a different ListAdapter in the program. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  Remember, it's okay to answer your own question.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' using the green checkmark so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Will do, still got another 3 hours on it apparently. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
image.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
label.setText("LABEL");
```

if we don't enter the if statement image and label objects are not instantiated and you will get a null pointer exception when you call setBackroundColr, and setText try:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.v("Hyperion","convertView is Null?="+Boolean.toString(convertView==null));
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(net.blakely.paul.Hyperion.R.layout.outputitem, null, true);

        } 
          image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(net.blakely.paul.Hyperion.R.id.imageView1);
          label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(net.blakely.paul.Hyperion.R.id.textView2);
        // Decide which channel this is and set information accordingly

        image.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        label.setText("LABEL");
```

Comment: That unfortunately, didn't work. Image still winds up being null.